# `browseURL("mydoc.docx")` doesn't work anymore

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

A few RStudio versions ago, I often used `browseURL("mydoc.docx")` to open files with MS Word or MS Excel.

Now, this code just does nothing, with no warning or error.

I can open PDF files and URLs with no issue, this seems to happen only with MS Office.

I suspect it has to do with `getOption("browser")`, which points to `.Call("rs_browseURL", url, PACKAGE = "(embedding)")` in my case.

Is there any way I can get debug this behavior?

I'm working on Windows 10 using RStudio 2023.03.0+386, both at work and at home.

##### EDIT

Here are my further try:

```r
file.exists("mydoc.docx")
#> TRUE
browseURL("mydoc.docx", browser = NULL)
#> Error in shell.exec(url) : 'mydoc.docx' not found
```

Thanks to @RitchieSacramento, `browseURL(normalizePath("mydoc.docx"))` works!

Comment: I can't replicate your issue.  Have you tried `browseURL("mydoc.docx", browser = NULL)`?

Comment: @RitchieSacramento hmm interesting so that's probably a local problem. Thanks for the idea but that doesn't work either, I added the output to my question.

Comment: It should use the working directory if a full path hasn't been specified - but the behavior you've described is what happens when a file doesn't exist (i.e. nothing happens) and it seems to be confirmed by the error message when you called `browseURL("mydoc.docx", browser = NULL)` that it's not looking in the right place.  Try with a full path to the file and see if it works.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Genius! `browseURL(normalizePath("mydoc.docx"))` works! Now, do you think there is a way to avoid this additional call?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what the root cause is. Hopefully someone else can chime in with a suggestion.  Have you tried different files and different working directories?  Any non-ASCII characters in the filenames or file paths?

Comment: @RitchieSacramento only ASCII characters, but including spaces. I can open PDF with no issue though.

Comment: This seems odd. `browseURL("mydoc.docx")` by itself works when I'm in the same directory, but if I'm in the parent (or a child), `"path/mydoc.docx"` does not work despite it clearly being there, but `"path\\mydoc.docx"` (backslashes) does work. Further, `"/abs/path/mydoc.docx"` doesn't work, but `"c:/abs/path/mydoc.docx"` does (_forward_ slashes), which is similar to (but not perfectly the same as) the use of `normalizePath`. To me this is counter-intuitive, I too am very interested in the inconsistent behavior.

Comment: On the same RStudio version with R 4.2.2 & Windows 11. Can't replicate the issue. All the variations described by r2evans work for me (i.e. 2 x back slashes vs 1 x forward slash, relative vs. absolute path).